# How to define multi segment url like /project/collaborator in react router 5

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to define a multi-segment URL in react-router-dom but unfortunately, it's not working, can anyone let me know where is the problem?

```
<React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Switch>

          <Layout path="/" component={HComponent} exact /> //working
          <Layout path="/calender" component={CComponent} exact /> // working
          
          //Not working
          <Layout path="/calender/today" component={CComponent} exact />

        </Switch>
      </Router>
</React.Fragment>
```

Where do I need to change?

Comment: Try to move the more specific route (`/calendar/today`) _above_ the less specific route (`/calendar`). Just out of curiosity, though, are you sure you are rendering a different component for that route? The code you pasted above is rendering the same component for both routes– which would make it seem like the more specific route is not working.

Comment: As Labu explained, for this you should just nest the routers. Basically, create another router inside the component that should take in extra `/today`. A demo of how to nest routes can be found here: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting